# Disable plugin only for one post

Tags: plugins, customization

It's possible to disable a plugin just for a post?

I'm displaying a post in my footer but I've installed **Simple Facebook Share Button** and I don't know how to remove that button.

Unfortunately I can't use css to hide the button :(

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a custom query in the footer that includes the post? If so, please try the following code before the loop the displays the footer post:

```
<?php remove_filter( 'the_content', 'SFBSB_auto' ); ?>
```